# can't get facebook access token from java filter, error HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am trying to setup a prototype environment and communicate with facebook. I have set up a test java application and I serve it through my static ip. For the facebook part I have implemented the example of this friend

http://www.richardnichols.net/2010/06/implementing-facebook-oauth-2-0-authentication-in-java/

To solve any questions you may have regarding general connectivity with facebook, I have started my own page tab application with the below information

Page Tab URL: http://[MYIP]:8080/facebookContest/app/index.do
Secure Page Tab URL:https://[MYIP]:8443/facebookContest/app/index.do

I have already checked that both urls are functional and do return my "hello world" localy. I added this application to a test facebook page that I created, using this url:
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=[MYAPPID]&next=http://[MYIP]:8080/facebookContest/app/index.do

FYI, If I disable all facebook authorization/communication logic, the static content of the application is shown correctly inside facebook. So it seems that an initial communication with facebook is established.

The Facebook.java code

```
    package com.facebookContest.fb;

    import com.visural.common.StringUtil;



    public class Facebook {
        // get these from your FB Dev App
        private static final String api_key = "[MYKEY]";     
        private static final String secret = "MYSECRET";
        private static final String client_id = "[MYKEY]";  

        // set this to your servlet URL for the authentication servlet/filter
        private static final String redirect_uri = "http://[MYIP]:8080/facebookContest/app/index.do"; 
        /// set this to the list of extended permissions you want
        private static final String[] perms = new String[] {"publish_stream", "email"};

        public static String getAPIKey() {
            return api_key;
        }

        public static String getSecret() {
            return secret;
        }

        public static String getLoginRedirectURL() {
            return "http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + 
                client_id + "&display=page&redirect_uri=" + 
                redirect_uri+"&scope="+StringUtil.delimitObjectsToString(",", perms);
        }

        public static String getAuthURL(String authCode) {
            return "http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + 
                client_id+"&redirect_uri=" + 
                redirect_uri+"&client_secret="+secret+"&code="+authCode;
        }
    }
```

the FacebookUserService.java

```
    package com.facebookContest.fb;

    import java.net.URL;

    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import com.visural.common.IOUtil;

    class FacebookUserService {



        public void authFacebookLogin(String accessToken, int expires) {
            try {
                JSONObject resp = new JSONObject(
                    IOUtil.urlToString(new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + accessToken)));
                String id = resp.getString("id");
                String firstName = resp.getString("first_name");
                String lastName = resp.getString("last_name");
                String email = resp.getString("email");


                // custom code


            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("failed login", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

My filter class FBOAuth.java code:

```
    package com.facebookContest.fb;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.URL;


    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

    import com.visural.common.StringUtil;


    public class FBOAuth implements Filter {

        @Autowired
        FacebookUserService facebookUserService;

        public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
        }

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest srvlReq, ServletResponse srvReq, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)srvlReq;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)srvReq;

            String code = srvlReq.getParameter("signed_request");

            if (StringUtil.isNotBlankStr(code)) {
                String authURL = Facebook.getAuthURL(code);
                URL url = new URL(authURL);

                try {

                    String result = readURL(url);
                    String accessToken = null;
                    Integer expires = null;
                    String[] pairs = result.split("&");

                    for (String pair : pairs) {
                        String[] kv = pair.split("=");
                        if (kv.length != 2) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected auth response");
                        } else {
                            if (kv[0].equals("access_token")) {
                                accessToken = kv[1];
                            }
                            if (kv[0].equals("expires")) {
                                expires = Integer.valueOf(kv[1]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (accessToken != null && expires != null) {
                        facebookUserService.authFacebookLogin(accessToken, expires);
                        response.sendRedirect("http://[MYIP]:8080/facebookContest/app/index.do");
                    } else {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Access token and expires not found");
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }       
        }

        private String readURL(URL url) throws IOException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            int r;
            while ((r = is.read()) != -1) {
                baos.write(r);
            }
            return new String(baos.toByteArray());
        }

        public void destroy() {
        }
     }
```

on line 45 
`String result = readURL(url);`

The filter does a get with the following url as copied from the debugger -seems correct to me-

http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[MYAPPID]&redirect_uri=http://[MYIP]:8080/facebookContest/app/index.do&client_secret=[MYAPPSECRET]&code=s0PmZHCK9Vl2tBzIGLDJbJJ4uiVUTIkU2KiknGboLrI.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTM1ODUwNDY0NiwicGFnZSI6eyJpZCI6IjM1NDcxOTMwNDYzNTQ4MSIsImxpa2VkIjpmYWxzZSwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9LCJ1c2VyIjp7ImNvdW50cnkiOiJnciIsImxvY2FsZSI6ImVsX0dSIiwiYWdlIjp7Im1pbiI6MjF9fX0

The exception thrown on `String result = readURL(url);` is this

```
    java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[MYAPPID]&redirect_uri=http://[MYIP]:8080/facebookContest/app/index.do&client_secret=[MYAPPSECRET]&code=GdbObQHyYPvIKnkShMBv8Wry-UNPAQWAMmSVyXe5n_k.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTM1ODUwNDQ4OCwicGFnZSI6eyJpZCI6IjM1NDcxOTMwNDYzNTQ4MSIsImxpa2VkIjpmYWxzZSwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9LCJ1c2VyIjp7ImNvdW50cnkiOiJnciIsImxvY2FsZSI6ImVsX0dSIiwiYWdlIjp7Im1pbiI6MjF9fX0
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
        at com.facebookContest.fb.FBOAuth.readURL(FBOAuth.java:78)
        at com.facebookContest.fb.FBOAuth.doFilter(FBOAuth.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Ιαν 18, 2013 12:21:30 ΜΜ org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [facebookContest] in context with path [/facebookContest] threw exception
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[MYAPPID]&redirect_uri=http://[MYIP]:8080/facebookContest/app/index.do&client_secret=[MYAPPSECRET]&code=GdbObQHyYPvIKnkShMBv8Wry-UNPAQWAMmSVyXe5n_k.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTM1ODUwNDQ4OCwicGFnZSI6eyJpZCI6IjM1NDcxOTMwNDYzNTQ4MSIsImxpa2VkIjpmYWxzZSwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9LCJ1c2VyIjp7ImNvdW50cnkiOiJnciIsImxvY2FsZSI6ImVsX0dSIiwiYWdlIjp7Im1pbiI6MjF9fX0
        at com.facebookContest.fb.FBOAuth.doFilter(FBOAuth.java:71)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[MYAPPID]&redirect_uri=http://[MYIP]:8080/facebookContest/app/index.do&client_secret=[MYAPPSECRET]&code=GdbObQHyYPvIKnkShMBv8Wry-UNPAQWAMmSVyXe5n_k.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTM1ODUwNDQ4OCwicGFnZSI6eyJpZCI6IjM1NDcxOTMwNDYzNTQ4MSIsImxpa2VkIjpmYWxzZSwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9LCJ1c2VyIjp7ImNvdW50cnkiOiJnciIsImxvY2FsZSI6ImVsX0dSIiwiYWdlIjp7Im1pbiI6MjF9fX0
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
        at com.facebookContest.fb.FBOAuth.readURL(FBOAuth.java:78)
        at com.facebookContest.fb.FBOAuth.doFilter(FBOAuth.java:44)
        ... 16 more
```

I believe that my spring/hibernate configuration is not needed, as the application seems to function properly. If anyone needs it though there is no problem providing it.

I have already read several posts indicating the error on the redirect_uri. I have checked it over and over and this is not the case. The application tab is installed on the page with the exact uri that I call when the exception is thrown.

I also couldn't find an answer here
[HTTP 400 error when trying to get access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333150/http-400-error-when-trying-to-get-access-token)

Please feel free to direct me on any piece of documentation that might help.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem so I thought I could share the solution, if anyone else reaches this problem.

The error message of the exception comes with a json response with more information. What you could do to see the response is just paste the url that you construct to any browser. I do it as shown below.

```
    public static String getAuthURL(String authCode) {
            return "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"+
                    "client_id=" + client_id +
                    "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + 
                    "&client_secret=" + secret + 
                    "&code=" + authCode;
        }
```

The error message will be displayed. And will give you information about what went wrong. In my case I was trying the authorization GET through http and the error message directed that such action, should be done over https.

I corrected this problem and I finally got the access_token.